# How to connect g_signal_connect in gtk without callig new function with G_CALLBACK ()

Tags: c, gtk

So I have code which go like this, my main

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
button = GTK_WIDGET( gtk_builder_get_object( builder, "button2" ) );
g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (show_dialog), NULL);
}
```

Then I have show_dialog which go like this

```
static void
show_dialog ( GtkWidget *button,
          gint       response_id,
          gpointer   user_data )
{
GtkBuilder *builder;
GtkWidget *filechoosedialog;

builder = gtk_builder_new();
gtk_builder_add_from_file( builder, GLADE_FILE, NULL );
fiilechoosedialog = GTK_WIDGET( gtk_builder_get_object(  
                                builder, 
                                "filechooserdialog1" ) );
/* Run dialog */
gtk_dialog_run( GTK_DIALOG( filechoosedialog ) );
gtk_widget_hide( filechoosedialog );

gtk_builder_connect_signals( builder, NULL );

g_object_unref( G_OBJECT(builder));
}
```

So now I would like to add this part to show dialog so I could detect when Open and Cancel buttons are pressed. In Glade I seted response id of Open button to be -5 and cancel to be -6 which corespond to GTK_RESPONSE_OK and GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL but when I press Open button I do not get g_print executed

```
switch (response_id)
{
  case GTK_RESPONSE_OK:

        g_print ("Selected filename: %s\n", filename);
        g_print ("response idd: %d\n", response_id);
     break;
  default:

     break;
}
```

gtk_widget_destroy (GTK_WIDGET (filechoosedialog));

Answer (score 1):

`GtkFileChooserDialog` is a subclass to `GtkDialog`, so using `gint gtk_dialog_run(GtkDialog *dialog);` should work, which returns the response code.

---

```
// get hold of the return value of `gtk_run_dialog(...)`, lookup the type
response_id = gtk_dialog_run( GTK_DIALOG( filechoosedialog ) );
switch (response_id)
{
  case GTK_RESPONSE_OK:
        g_print ("Selected filename: %s\n", filename);
        g_print ("response idd: %d\n", response_id);
     break;
  default:
        g_print ("do'h! no file selected!\n");
     break;
}

// I am pretty sure you do not need this, this approach does not use the `updated` signal
gtk_builder_connect_signals( builder, NULL );
```

Comment: But it does not work I get nothing as response_id. I get filename but dialog does not emit response_id although I seted up buttons response ID to be -5 for Ok and -6 for Cancel

Comment: Can you please update your code (please make it comeplete and compileable), it is not clear what exactly is going wrong from what you say or where you expect the response code to appear nor where you placed `gtk_dialog_run` - which is an important delay.

Comment: There is update of my code is it now more clear, tnx @drahnr for your help

Comment: Updated, I think that should work, you still need to lookup the type the response id is of, `gint` should work but it is somewhat dirty, use the correct enum.

Comment: Yup it works now response_id = gtk_dialog_run( GTK_DIALOG( filechoosedialog ) ); Thanks Drahnr